# How to kill a windows service containing multiple background services from within the service

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Windows Service built in .NET Core 3.1. The service contains multiple BackGroundService classes that each performs an action. Each Background service has a loop similar to:

```
   while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      // do stuff 
   }
```

In one of those BackgroundService implementations, I want to be able to (under specific conditions) stop the entire windows service.

So, basically, I need to know how to get access to the CancellationTokens of all the other services (or some equivalent way of killing the entire service).

I have tried the sledgehammer approach (  Environment.Exit(-1); ). This seems to work  - but it hangs after printing out a line stating that it is waiting for the IHost to dispose. I'm guessing this means that Environment.Exit didn't trigger the cancellationtokens? (Or, I have one thread that is hanging on for dear life and possibly not listening to it's cancellationtoken....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime` into your service and call `StopApplication` when needed.